# Can we upvote posts if we want the opposite user to go into a chat?

Tags: discussion

Can we upvote posts if we want the opposite user to go into a chat? For example, if the user has 1 rep and wants to go into a chat, can we upvote his posts?

Comment: There is no requirement for a long conversation to immediately go to chat. Chat is offered up as an alternative because it's better for discussion. If the OP can't participate there, clearly it's not a valid alternative for that case.

Comment: If content requires so much discussion that chat is more appropriate than comments... that seems more like a reason to consider downvoting than upvoting!

Comment: x-site duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199827/is-it-okay-to-upvote-someones-questions-so-i-can-speak-with-them-in-chat

Comment: Sounds like a form of serially upvoting which isn't allowed.  If such a discussion is required, to answer the question, the question should be clarified.

Comment: Somewhat related (the same problem, with a different threshold): *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Can we upvote posts if we want the opposite user to go into a chat?

No, absolutely not. You should vote on the quality and site-appropriateness of content, nothing more and nothing less. Your vote on a question (and an answer) is meant to reflect your perception of the value of the question/answer and its potential benefit of future visitors so that good ones can rise to the top while questions of lesser value will sink. You are not voting for the benefit of a poster.

To vote on a question or answer for any other reason is inappropriate.

---

On the separate issue of comment thread length, if a question requires a huge comment thread to achieve clarity, then the question may not be ready for this site just yet, and as others have suggested, may need a down-vote or close-vote, again based on content alone.

Also, if the poster is requesting in comment an up-vote to allow them to enter chat, then flag the comment as "no longer necessary", or if the request is repeated or is egregious, then flag with a custom flag requesting moderator action.

Comment: Hmmmmmm. So, is it ok if the conversation goes too big?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal: No, that's not okay *either*.  That usually means that there's a bigger problem in that the OP doesn't have all of the details in their question, or they're trying to get you to hand-hold them through the process.

Comment: And what if i am unable to understand him but he is clear to others?

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal: Comment thread length that is a separate issue, one unrelated to voting, but in my mind, If a conversation gets big, then the question may not be fully appropriate for this site (yet), since it remains unclear. Comment conversations should mainly be about improving question clarity, and the OP should then edit the question accordingly (if they agree).

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal:  If *only* you can't understand the question, but *everyone else* can, then you should probably...refrain.  If others are clear on the question that the OP is asking about, then you asking clarifying questions because you're not on the same page is just as distracting as if they were the one who was asking lots of questions.